# Picking json objects those are between the lookup ranges using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of objects with each object containing id, type and x and y cordinates

They are classified as follows

- id > a unique identifier to determine the groups
- type > within the id group of elements, this type is wither k or f where f is a superset and k is subset (f is a lookup array)
- x and y are cordinates

1. Now i need to extract all the objects of given array in such a way
   that,
2. group the given array based on id, so we have 2 arrays for below
   example 5WExPztSqk and 8ciNkiJBjg
3. after grouping them again classify the lookup (type=f) and key
   objects (type=k)
4. display the k type objects if the x and y of k is falls within ANY
   of the type f x and y objects

The sample and expected results are shown in the code below. I have tried my best but unable to get into track

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>


var x =[{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"f","element":{},"x":7,"y":7},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":6,"y":6},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":7,"y":7},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":8,"y":8},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"f","element":{},"x":11,"y":13},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":10,"y":10},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":11,"y":11},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":12,"y":12},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":13,"y":13},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":14,"y":14},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"f","element":{},"x":19,"y":25},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":16,"y":16},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":17,"y":17},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":18,"y":18},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":19,"y":19},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":20,"y":20},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":21,"y":21},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":22,"y":22},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":23,"y":23},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":24,"y":24},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":25,"y":25},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":26,"y":26},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":27,"y":27},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":28,"y":28},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":30,"y":30},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":31,"y":31},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":32,"y":32},{"id":"5WExPztSqk","type":"k","element":{},"x":15,"y":15},{"id":"5WExPztSqk","type":"k","element":{},"x":16,"y":16},{"id":"5WExPztSqk","type":"f","element":{},"x":19,"y":21},{"id":"5WExPztSqk","type":"k","element":{},"x":18,"y":18},{"id":"5WExPztSqk","type":"k","element":{},"x":19,"y":19},{"id":"5WExPztSqk","type":"k","element":{},"x":20,"y":20},{"id":"5WExPztSqk","type":"k","element":{},"x":21,"y":21},{"id":"5WExPztSqk","type":"k","element":{},"x":22,"y":22}]


/*Expected result

lookup1_input_from_xObj = [{
    "id": "8ciNkiJBjg",
    "type": "f",
    "element": {},
    "x": 7,
    "y": 7
}, {
    "id": "8ciNkiJBjg",
    "type": "f",
    "element": {},
    "x": 11,
    "y": 13
}, {
    "id": "8ciNkiJBjg",
    "type": "f",
    "element": {},
    "x": 19,
    "y": 25
}]

picked_from_lookup1_result_obtained = [ {
    "id": "8ciNkiJBjg",
    "type": "k",
    "element": {},
    "x": 7,
    "y": 7
}, {
    "id": "8ciNkiJBjg",
    "type": "k",
    "element": {},
    "x": 11,
    "y": 11
}, {
    "id": "8ciNkiJBjg",
    "type": "k",
    "element": {},
    "x": 12,
    "y": 12
}, {
    "id": "8ciNkiJBjg",
    "type": "k",
    "element": {},
    "x": 13,
    "y": 13
}, {
    "id": "8ciNkiJBjg",
    "type": "k",
    "element": {},
    "x": 19,
    "y": 19
}, {
    "id": "8ciNkiJBjg",
    "type": "k",
    "element": {},
    "x": 20,
    "y": 20
}, {
    "id": "8ciNkiJBjg",
    "type": "k",
    "element": {},
    "x": 21,
    "y": 21
}, {
    "id": "8ciNkiJBjg",
    "type": "k",
    "element": {},
    "x": 22,
    "y": 22
}, {
    "id": "8ciNkiJBjg",
    "type": "k",
    "element": {},
    "x": 23,
    "y": 23
}, {
    "id": "8ciNkiJBjg",
    "type": "k",
    "element": {},
    "x": 24,
    "y": 24
}, {
    "id": "8ciNkiJBjg",
    "type": "k",
    "element": {},
    "x": 25,
    "y": 25
}]



lookup2_input_from_xObj = [

{"id":"5WExPztSqk","type":"f","element":{},"x":19,"y":21},

]

picked_from_lookup2_result_obtained = 

{
    "id": "5WExPztSqk",
    "type": "k",
    "element": {},
    "x": 19,
    "y": 19
}, {
    "id": "5WExPztSqk",
    "type": "k",
    "element": {},
    "x": 20,
    "y": 20
}, {
    "id": "5WExPztSqk",
    "type": "k",
    "element": {},
    "x": 21,
    "y": 21
},

*/

var groups = {};

for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
    //separate based on id (includes type=k and type=f)
}

groups["5WExPztSqk"] //will have all the objects of type k and f of id = 5WExPztSqk
groups["8ciNkiJBjg"] //will have all the objects of type k and f of id = 8ciNkiJBjg

for each of the groups {
    //separate group by type
    var typefarray = group typef elements; //lookup array
    var typekarray = group typek elements; //lookup array
    
    
    if(typekarray x and y is within any of lookup array x and y)
        result.push(x[i])
    else
        ;//ignore the object

}



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you mean by "range"? If `x` and `y` are cordinates, an array of these objects (e.g. `lookup1`) represents a series of ponits instead of an interval.

Comment: x and y values are numbers range mean 3 to 10 where 3 is start (x) and 10 is end (y)

Comment: @RameshReddy Yes correct lookup1 input and picked_from_lookup1 the output. I renamed to avoid confusion.

Comment: @RameshReddy within means if Kx = 4 and Ky=5, If I have a lookup of Fx = 2 and Fy = 10, then 4 and 5 values falls within the range 2 and 5

Comment: @CodeGuy Okay, check my answer. Grouping, classifying are not needed for the output you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

1. Group by id
2. for each group find the `fArr`(elements of type 'f') and `kArr`(elements of type 'k')
3. filter the `kArr` based on the ranges in `fArr`

Check the below snippet:

```js
const fullArr = [
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'f', element: {}, x: 7, y: 7 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 6, y: 6 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 7, y: 7 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 8, y: 8 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'f', element: {}, x: 11, y: 13 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 10, y: 10 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 11, y: 11 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 12, y: 12 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 13, y: 13 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 14, y: 14 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'f', element: {}, x: 19, y: 25 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 16, y: 16 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 17, y: 17 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 18, y: 18 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 19, y: 19 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 20, y: 20 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 21, y: 21 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 22, y: 22 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 23, y: 23 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 24, y: 24 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 25, y: 25 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 26, y: 26 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 27, y: 27 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 28, y: 28 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 30, y: 30 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 31, y: 31 },
  { id: '8ciNkiJBjg', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 32, y: 32 },
  { id: '5WExPztSqk', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 15, y: 15 },
  { id: '5WExPztSqk', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 16, y: 16 },
  { id: '5WExPztSqk', type: 'f', element: {}, x: 19, y: 21 },
  { id: '5WExPztSqk', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 18, y: 18 },
  { id: '5WExPztSqk', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 19, y: 19 },
  { id: '5WExPztSqk', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 20, y: 20 },
  { id: '5WExPztSqk', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 21, y: 21 },
  { id: '5WExPztSqk', type: 'k', element: {}, x: 22, y: 22 },
];


const compute = (fullArr) => {
  const groupedById = fullArr.reduce((acc, el) => {
    return acc.set(el.id, [...(acc.get(el.id) || []), el]);
  }, new Map());

  groupedById.forEach((v) => {
    const fArr = v.filter((el) => el.type === 'f');
    const kArr = v.filter((el) => el.type === 'k');

    const result = kArr.filter((kEl) => {
      return fArr.some((fEl) => kEl.x >= fEl.x && kEl.y <= fEl.y);
    });

    console.log('lookupArr', fArr);
    console.log('result', result);
  });
};

compute(fullArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based your comments I wrote this:

```js
var x =[{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"f","element":{},"x":7,"y":7},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":6,"y":6},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":7,"y":7},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":8,"y":8},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"f","element":{},"x":11,"y":13},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":10,"y":10},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":11,"y":11},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":12,"y":12},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":13,"y":13},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":14,"y":14},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"f","element":{},"x":19,"y":25},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":16,"y":16},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":17,"y":17},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":18,"y":18},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":19,"y":19},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":20,"y":20},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":21,"y":21},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":22,"y":22},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":23,"y":23},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":24,"y":24},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":25,"y":25},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":26,"y":26},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":27,"y":27},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":28,"y":28},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":30,"y":30},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":31,"y":31},{"id":"8ciNkiJBjg","type":"k","element":{},"x":32,"y":32},{"id":"5WExPztSqk","type":"k","element":{},"x":15,"y":15},{"id":"5WExPztSqk","type":"k","element":{},"x":16,"y":16},{"id":"5WExPztSqk","type":"f","element":{},"x":19,"y":21},{"id":"5WExPztSqk","type":"k","element":{},"x":18,"y":18},{"id":"5WExPztSqk","type":"k","element":{},"x":19,"y":19},{"id":"5WExPztSqk","type":"k","element":{},"x":20,"y":20},{"id":"5WExPztSqk","type":"k","element":{},"x":21,"y":21},{"id":"5WExPztSqk","type":"k","element":{},"x":22,"y":22}];

function getGroups(arr){
  const groups = {};
  arr.forEach(e => {
    if(!groups[e.id]){
      groups[e.id] = [];
    }
    groups[e.id].push(e);
  });
  return groups;
}

function getLookups(arr){
  return arr.filter(e => e.type === "f");
}

function picking(arr, lower, upper){
  return arr.filter(e => e.type === "k" && 
                  e.x >= lower && e.x <= upper && 
                  e.y >= lower && e.y <= upper);
}

function getPicked(arr, lookup){
  const ret = [];
  lookup.forEach(e => {
    ret.push(picking(arr, e.x, e.y));
   });
   return ret.flat();
 }

const groups = getGroups(x);

const lookup1 = getLookups(Object.values(groups["8ciNkiJBjg"]));
const lookup2 = getLookups(Object.values(groups["5WExPztSqk"]));

const picked_from_lookup1 = getPicked(Object.values(groups["8ciNkiJBjg"]), lookup1);
const picked_from_lookup2 = getPicked(Object.values(groups["5WExPztSqk"]), lookup2);

console.log(lookup1);
console.log(picked_from_lookup1);

console.log(lookup2);
console.log(picked_from_lookup2);
```